# PHP 5.3.3 Database not connecting

Tags: php, pdo

I have upgraded my PHP from 5.2.17 to 5.3.3. My database has stopped working. I have checked
     much of the code an keep getting the following error. Any ideas on what I can try??

Error - Array [0] => 00000 [1] =>  [2] =>

```
``//============================================================================    
 private  function _Init($db)
           {
                if($db) 
                    $this->DB = $db; 
                else
                {
                    $E = new ErrorMsg("Invalid db connection".$this->DB->DataBase,"Error",__FILE__);
                    $E->Show();
                    return;
                }
           }
           //============================================================================
           public function Connect()
           {
               if(!class_exists("PDO"))
               {
                  $E = new ErrorMsg("On your server is not instaled PDO library!","Fatal Error",__FILE__);
                  $E->Show();
               }

               try
               {
                 $this->PDO =  new PDO("mysql:host=".$this->DB->ServerName."; dbname=".$this->DB->DataBase,
                                       $this->DB->UserName,
                                       $this->DB->Password, array( PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => false ,PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY=>true));
               }
               catch(PDOException $t)
               {

                  $E = new ErrorMsg("Not connected to DB ".$this->DB->DataBase,"Error",__FILE__);
                  $E->Show();
                  return;
               }

           }
           //============================================================================
           public function Query($Q,$Values=array())
           {

              if(!$this->PDO) return;

              $this->_cPDOStatement = null;
              $R = $this->PDO->prepare($Q);


              if($this->PDO->errorInfo()==array('0'=>'00000'))
              {
                  $R->execute($Values);

                  if($R->errorInfo()==array('0'=>'00000'))
                  {
                    $this->_cPDOStatement = $R;
                    return $this->_cPDOStatement;
                  }
                  else
                  {
                       $E = new ErrorMsg($R->errorInfo(),"Error",__FILE__);
                       $E->Show();
                  }
              }
              else
              {
                 $E = new ErrorMsg($this->PDO->errorInfo(),"Error",__FILE__);
                 $E->Show();
              }

              return null;
           }
           //============================================================================
           public function GetLastInsertedId()
           {
              return $this->PDO->lastInsertId();
           }
           //============================================================================
           public function FetchObj( $PDOStat=null )
           {
                if($PDOStat)
                {
                    return $PDOStat->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
                }
                else
                {
                    if($this->_cPDOStatement)
                    {
                        $Result = $this->_cPDOStatement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
                        $this->_cPDOStatement = null;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $Result = null;
                    }
                }

                return $Result;
           }
           //============================================================================
           public function FetchArray( $PDOStat=null )
           {
                if($PDOStat)
                {

                    return $PDOStat->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                }
                else
                {
                    if($this->_cPDOStatement)
                    {

                        $Result = $this->_cPDOStatement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                        $this->_cPDOStatement = null;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $Result = null;
                    }
                }

                return $Result;
           }
           //============================================================================
           public function FetchAllObj( $PDOStat=null )
           {
                if($PDOStat)
                {
                    return $PDOStat->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
                }
                else
                {
                    if($this->_cPDOStatement)
                    {
                        $Result = $this->_cPDOStatement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
                        $this->_cPDOStatement = null;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $Result = null;
                    }
                }

                return $Result;
           }
           //============================================================================
           public function FetchAllAssoc( $PDOStat=null )
           {
                if($PDOStat)
                {
                    return $PDOStat->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                }
                else
                {
                    if($this->_cPDOStatement)
                    {
                        $Result = $this->_cPDOStatement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                        $this->_cPDOStatement = null;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $Result = null;
                    }
                }

                return $Result;
           }
           //============================================================================
           public function FetchAllArray( $PDOStat=null )
           {
                if($PDOStat)
                {
                    return $PDOStat->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                }
                else
                {
                    if($this->_cPDOStatement)
                    {
                        $Result = $this->_cPDOStatement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                        $this->_cPDOStatement = null;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $Result = null;
                    }
                }

                return $Result;
           }
           //============================================================================
           public function Disconnect()
           {
              $this->PDO = null;
           }
        }

    ?>`
```

Comment: What method of solving this problem have you tried?

Comment: Where are you setting ServerName, UserName and Password or calling Connect method!

Comment: Your are catching the exception – but you completely disregard its message content, only to make up your own, not very informative, error message … put `var_dump($t);` into your exception catch statement!

Comment: Hi, It is another programmer who has been trying...he has tried several rewrites but still cant connect! We cant fully identify the problem. Were new to PHP.

Comment: make a new php file, and do JUST the connection AND echo your error, no PDO no queries, just a simple database connection

Comment: go to your command line and check put `php -v` which is your default version of  php and then put `phpinfo();` in one of php file and check which php version it use. may be there some different.